# Rails virtual model without serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering, what would be the best option to implement a virtual model.

Let's say we have users, we would like them to have a gender attribute.

The easiest option would be to have a `Gender` model and then do a `belongs_to :gender`

Then, each time you ask for a user, it will also perform a `SELECT` on the genders table

Therefore, does anyone have an idea on how to implement  a virtual model that would not be persisted in the database and just be a regular model with the ability through the `belongs_to association` to perform a select on `Male` or `female` ?

I know I could just use Serialization but I feel like it's a bit of a waste of memory/space/ressources to store a serialized object each time I create a user and would definitely love a solution where I can use the traditional gender_id:integer ...

Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [`enum` field (Rails 4.1+)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums), which allows its **value to be within a predefined set of values** (you can *enumerate* them, hence the name). It is **persisted as a plain integer** in database, but convenience methods are generated for easily manipulating them:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: [ :male, :female ]
end

user.male!
user.female? # => false
user.gender  # => "male"

User.male # => a collection of users with "male" specified in gender

Conversation.genders # => { "male" => 0, "female" => 1 }
```